# ReactJs - Redirect on Login redirects for a second, then returns to login page

Tags: reactjs, authentication, redirect, routes, react-router-dom

I have a login component, and on successful login, it should redirect to the /home page. When user clicks the Login button, it does redirect to the Home page for a brief second, then returns to the Login page. However, the user access token is stored, and I can manually navigate back to the Home page. I am not sure what is causing the login to redirect back to the Login page after successful login.  Here is my code:

Login.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Form from "react-validation/build/form";
import Input from "react-validation/build/input";
import CheckButton from "react-validation/build/button";
import { Container, Row, Col, Button } from 'react-bootstrap';

import AuthService from "../../../services/authService";


const required = value => {
    if (!value) {
      return (
        <div className="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
          This field is required!
        </div>
      );
    }
  };

export default class Login extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.handleLogin = this.handleLogin.bind(this);
        this.onChangeUsername = this.onChangeUsername.bind(this);
        this.onChangePassword = this.onChangePassword.bind(this);

        this.state = {
            username: '',
            password: '',
            loading: false,
            message: ''
        };
    }

    onChangeUsername(e) {
        this.setState({ 
            username: e.target.value
        });
    }

    onChangePassword(e) {
        this.setState({ 
            password: e.target.value
        });
    }

    handleLogin(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    
        this.setState({
          message: '',
          loading: true
        });
        this.form.validateAll();

        if (this.checkBtn.context._errors.length === 0) {
          AuthService.login(this.state.username, this.state.password).then(
            () => {
              this.props.history.push("/home");
              window.location.reload();
            },
            error => {
              const resMessage =
                (error.response &&
                  error.response.data &&
                  error.response.data.message) ||
                error.message ||
                error.toString();
    
              this.setState({
                loading: false,
                message: resMessage
              });
            }
          );
        } else {
          this.setState({
            loading: false
          });
        }
      }


    render() {
        return (
            <Container className='login-container'>
                         <Form
            onSubmit={this.handleLogin}
            ref={c => {
              this.form = c;
            }}
          >
            <div className="form-group">
              <label htmlFor="username">Username</label>
              <Input
                type="text"
                className="form-control"
                name="username"
                value={this.state.username}
                onChange={this.onChangeUsername}
                validations={[required]}
              />
            </div>

            <div className="form-group">
              <label htmlFor="password">Password</label>
              <Input
                type="password"
                className="form-control"
                name="password"
                value={this.state.password}
                onChange={this.onChangePassword}
                validations={[required]}
              />
            </div>

            <div className="form-group">
              <button
                className="btn btn-primary btn-block"
                disabled={this.state.loading}
              >
                {this.state.loading && (
                  <span className="spinner-border spinner-border-sm"></span>
                )}
                <span>Login</span>
              </button>
            </div>

            {this.state.message && (
              <div className="form-group">
                <div className="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
                  {this.state.message}
                </div>
              </div>
            )}
            <CheckButton
              style={{ display: "none" }}
              ref={c => {
                this.checkBtn = c;
              }}
            />
          </Form>
            </Container>
        )
    }
}
```

App.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import './style/App.css';
import AuthService from './services/authService';
import PrivateRoute from './PrivateRoute';

import Navbar from './Navbar.js'

import Home from './modules/Home/components/Home';
import Pods from './modules/Pods/components/Pods';
import Onboarding from './modules/Onboarding/components/Onboarding';
import Login from './modules/Login/components/Login';



class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      currentUser: undefined,
      isLoggedIn: false
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const user = AuthService.getCurrentUser();
    if (user) {
      this.setState({
        currentUser: user,
        isLoggedIn: true
      })
    }
  }



  render() {
    const { isLoggedIn, currentUser } = this.state;
    console.log('is user logged in:' + isLoggedIn);
    return (
      <Router>      
          <Navbar isLoggedIn={isLoggedIn} logOut={this.logOut} />
          <div className="main-container">
            <Route path='/login' component={Login} />
            <PrivateRoute authed={isLoggedIn} path='/home' component={Home} />
          </div>
      </Router> 



    );
  }

}
export default App;
```

PrivateRoute.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Route, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';

const PrivateRoute = ({ authed, path, component}) => {

    return (
        authed
        ? <Route path={path} component={component} />
        : <Redirect to='/login' />
    )
}

export default PrivateRoute;
```

authService.js:

```
import axios from './axiosConfig';

class AuthService {
    login(username, password) {
      return axios
        .post('/api/auth/signin', {
          username,
          password
        })
        .then(response => {
          if (response.data.accessToken) {
            localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(response.data));
          }
  
          return response.data;
        });
    }
  
    logout() {
      localStorage.removeItem('user');
    }
  
    register(username, email, password) {
      return axios.post('/api/auth/signup', {
        username,
        email,
        password
      });
    }
  
    getCurrentUser() {
      return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));;
    }

    
  }
  
  export default new AuthService();
```

Any ideas? Thank you in advance!

Comment: in PrivateRoute.js; const isLoggedIn = localStorage.getItem('user') || false ;

Comment: return (
        isLoggedIn
        ? ....

Comment: Thank you, this small change worked!

Comment: anytime .......